# REGEX in MySQL to find Japanese matches

Tags: mysql, regex

I need to find all entries in a table that consist only out of certain Japanese UTF-8 characters.

For example, I want all fields that consist only out of 1 (一) and 2 (二).

I am using

```
SELECT combi_id, keb FROM combi WHERE keb REGEXP '[二一]+'
```

but it matches lots of other fields that contain different characters, what am I doing wrong?

This is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `combi` (
      `combi_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
      `ent_seq` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `reb` text NOT NULL,
      `keb` text NOT NULL,
      `ant` text NOT NULL,
      `ke_pri` text NOT NULL,
      `re_pri` text NOT NULL,
      `re_restr` text NOT NULL,
      `stagr` text NOT NULL,
      `s_inf` text NOT NULL,
      `lsource` text NOT NULL,
      `gloss` text NOT NULL,
      `xref` text NOT NULL,
      `stagk` text NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY  (`combi_id`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=146740 ;
```

and this is a sample line of data:

```
(22, 1000225, 'あからさま', '明白|偸閑|白地', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'plain|frank|candid|open|direct|straightforward|unabashed|blatant|flagrant', '', ''),
```

thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: I fixed this issue by [asking this question differently here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067566/unicode-in-mysql-regex

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match columns with *only* those characters, you should use

```
SELECT combi_id, keb FROM combi WHERE keb REGEXP '^[二一]+$'
```

Note the ^ in the beginning, and the $ in the end, meaning respectively "start of string" and "end of string". Without those, the regexp could match at any position.

Edit: testing it

```
mysql> select * from test;
+--------+
| f1     |
+--------+
| 二     |
| 東京   |
| 人     |
| 丸     |
+--------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from test where f1 regexp _utf8'[一二]';
+--------+
| f1     |
+--------+
| 二     |
| 東京   |
| 人     |
| 丸     |
+--------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Wow, indeed, character classes in mysql regexps sound seriously broken...
This works, though:

```
mysql> select * from test where f1 regexp _utf8'(一|二)';
+------+
| f1   |
+------+
| 二   |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! the issue is that this matches also results like
京, 人, 亀, 丸

Comment: Edited my post after some testing... It looks like mysql is broken. You may still use the | operator, it seems to work correctly.

Comment: the issue here is that it works only half. there are still some false positives if your sample is big enough. What i am doing now is pre-filtering with MySQL REgex and then iterating the result with a PHP regex. It seems that the mysql at least does list all the correct entries together with some wrong ones that I can filter out in another round.

Comment: Could you provide an example of a false positive, and the associated regexp? I checked the Mysql documentation, and they clearly state that regexps only work on single bytes (so this makes character classes basically unless on any kind of real-world text), but given the utf8 encoding rules, I do not see how the | operator could fail.