# Unicode in MySQL Regex?

Tags: php, mysql, regex, unicode

I have the following task: Build a personal dictionary for chinese characters. Users choose single chinese characters from a list. The software then goes through a list of combinations of characters and filters out all that contain characters that are not in the users list of single characters. So if the user studied 1(一) and 10 (十), then 11 (十一) should be shown, but not 12 (十二).

The next issue is that there are about 12k single characters and 100k combinations. The whole list can become very long. Currently I am facing the following issue: MySQL does not seem to be able to do proper REGEX matching with unicode characters. PHP can however. When I do a MySQL query (see below), I get a lot of false positives. I have to filter the results with PHP afterwards again. The whole thing takes a lot of time. I have now a sample list of 180 single charachters that are matched in a SQL regex as below. The result of the SQL are over 30'000 combinations. To do that SQL call takes about 6 seconds on the machine that I am running on. When I check the results with PHP afterwards, the result are only 1182 combinations. That's a lot of false positives. On top of that, checking the results takes another couple of seconds. With each single character I add to the list, the time increases by about half a second. A more effective method is needed urgently.

To tackle the issue, I first need to figure out why MySQL has so many false positives:

If I do regular expressions with PHP, I use a `/regex/u` to indicate that the subject is unicode and this gives me correct results.

In MySQL however, I do not know how do set such a flag. All  REGEXP 'regex' results are returned in the same way as if I used PHP `preg_match('/regex/', $subject)` instead of `/regex/u`.

I tried to change the collation of the result to various utf8_* but it would not change the result. Also adding a fulltext index over the database did not do anything.

Here is a testing-function that I wrote to highlight the issue. if you have any other ideas for checks to build in there to drill down on the problem please tell me.

```
$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'kanji', '************');
$link =  mysql_select_db('kanji_data', $db);
mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');
mysql_query('SET names=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_client=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');
mysql_query('SET collation_connection=utf8_general_ci');
mysql_set_charset('utf8');

echo '<pre>debug: encoding=' .mysql_client_encoding(). '</pre>';
$string = '三|二|四|一|五';
$sql = "SELECT simplified, length(simplified), searchindex FROM chinese WHERE strlen>0 AND simplified REGEXP '($string)+';";
$sql_encoding = mb_detect_encoding($sql);
echo '<pre>debug: sql string encoding: ' . $sql_encoding . '</pre>';
echo '<pre>debug: sql string: ' . $sql . '</pre>';
// echo $sql;
$rst = mysql_query($sql);
echo mysql_errno($db) . ": " . mysql_error($db). "\n";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rst, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    $len = mb_strlen($row[0]);
    $result_encoding =  mb_detect_encoding($row[0]);
    $pattern = "/^(三|二|四|一|五)+$/u";
    preg_match($pattern, $row[0], $matches);
    if (count($matches) == 0) {
        echo "ERROR: ";
    }
    echo 'string: '. $row[0] . ' ('.$row[1] .' long mysql, '.$len.' long php, encoding: '.$result_encoding.')'.$row[2] ."<br>\n\n\n";
}
```

The result of the function can be see [on this website](http://kanjifun.com/test.php).

If I am doing something completely wrong to achieve the required result, I am also happy to tackle this one differently.

Comment: "The result of the function can be see on this website." -> "You need to logged in to see this page" ;-)

Comment: sorry. please use guest/guest to login

Comment: MySQL does not have such flag because, unlike PHP, it *does* know the encoding of strings.

Comment: ok, I accept that it does not have a flag, but is there a way to get the same behavior as with PHP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue at hand is that MySQL cannot do REGEX in combination with Unicode characters properly at all. REGEX always works on a byte-basis and Unicode needs to group several bytes. There is no solution, only workarounds.

One workaround that I did was indexing every letter occurrences with another table and then running checks on the index instead of the original Japanese text.

Comment: Was this just a stunt to get a self-learner badge? Well hell, I'll give you a point...

Comment: Hehe nah. If you look when I originally asked that question you will see that this would have been a quite pre-meditated stunt... :) I am rather trying to close my open answers - got the revival badge for that, though ... Thanks for the point :)

Comment: Completely missed that! Going after the precog badge too huh? ;-)

Comment: Actually, I am just doing all kinds of weird stuff to randomly discover all the badges - Gotta catch'em all!

Answer (score 0):

Is the [connection charset](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html) also set to utf8?
Otherwise, if the connection charset is e.g. latin1, the mysql server interprets a (utf-8 encoded) statement like

```
SELECT x FROM foo WHERE name REGEXP 'Ä.*'
```

as

```
SELECT x FROM foo WHERE name REGEXP 'Ã„.*'
```

Comment: I have the following variables on the server:

`character set client  utf8
character set connection  utf8
character set database  latin1
character set filesystem  binary
character set results  utf8
character set server  latin1
character set system  utf8
collation connection  utf8_general_ci`

Comment: Which php module do you use to communicate with the mysql server? I.e. do you use mysql_query, mysqli_query, pdo, ...?

Comment: I am actually using the worddpress connector. Let me lookup how that is written.

Comment: It's using mysql_query(). By the way have the same issue of wrong results in the wordpress connector as well as in phpmyadmin

Comment: What is the output of `echo <pre>debug: encoding=', mysql_client_encoding(), '</pre>';` when you put it in your script right before the the regexp statement? And how do you build the statement (i.e. how do you make sure it contains an utf8 encoded string)? It would be beneficial if you could update your question an add an example script of the code you're using (i.e. a condesed version of the "real" script, just enough to show the "effect" of the real script).