# Why does mariadb regex give contrary result?

Tags: regex, mariadb

I have a column that contains following content:

```
+------------+
| name       |
+------------+
| 你好世界    |
| HelloWorld　|
| Hello世界 　|
+------------+
```

and I hope

```
SELECT `name` FROM `table`  WHERE `name` REGEXP '[u4e00-u9fa5]';
```

gives me only Chinese contained row like this:

```
+------------+
| name       |
+------------+
| 你好世界    |
+------------+
```

but it actually gives me contrary result:

```
+------------+
| name       |
+------------+
| HelloWorld　|
| Hello世界 　|
+------------+
```

I knew that:

```
SELECT `name` FROM `table`  WHERE `name` NOT REGEXP '[u4e00-u9fa5]';
```

can work as expected,but I want to know why mysql regexp gives contrary result?Is this the default setting?Or I made a mistake.Thanks in advance.

Comment: The class `[u4e00-u9fa5]` may contain `u, 4, e, 0, 9, f, a, 5` and all the characters between `0` and `u` (`[0-u]`). In this case only latin alphanumeric words would be matched. Are you sure that `u4e00` means U+4E00? Without any escape? Does MariaDB supports it or you should use `\p{xx}`?

Comment: MySQL regexp is not Unicode aware, as far as I know. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7606528/3832970. Perhaps, this post should be closed as a duplicate of that question.

Comment: No,I am not sure,but "NOT REGEXP " does give me the expected result.

Comment: `NOT REGEXP '[u4e00-u9fa5]'` means your results should not match a record that contains `u`, `4`, `e`, `0`, `9`, `f`, `a`, `5` (case insensitively), you do not match code points at all. You might get expected results but only for the current test data.

Comment: you are right,thanks

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38658540/how-to-use-regular-expression-to-match-word-without-any-letter-digital-or-specia

Answer (score 0):

If you are checking to see if a utf8 string has CJK characters in it:

```
WHERE HEX(name) REGEXP '^(..)*E[456789]'
```

That will not include the Chinese characters that are not in the "BMP" plane.