# How to use regular expression to match word without any letter,digital or special character?

Tags: sql, regex, mariadb

I want to use regular expression to filter out pure Chinese name by this:

```
SELECT `name` FROM `table`  WHERE `name` REGEXP '[u4e00-u9fa5]';
```

But, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14356248/does-mysql-regexp-support-unicode-matching#), it isn't possible,so I want to approach that from opposite direction,find content without any letter,digital and special character(I knew that it is not rigid),but can't find "and" operator,so how to do it?

Comment: Sorry, "words" without letters are impossible, right? Also, If there should be no word, nor special chars, do you need to only match whitespace or empty? Too unclear for me.

Comment: You can make a negative character class, like `[^A-Za-z0-9./,]`, and keep adding to it as necessary, but I'm not clear if that's what you're asking.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry,I mean Chinese character or word.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am using MariaDB

Comment: @AlexLuya: MariaDB uses PCRE, right? See [*Starting with MariaDB 10.0.5, MariaDB switched to the PCRE regular expression library for enhanced regular expressions.*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/pcre/) Try `REGEXP '[\\x{4e00}-\\x{9fa5}]'` or even `REGEXP '\\p{Han}'`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew,you suggestion can't handle combinations like:"A张方" and I want to get this kind of name out also.

Comment: @AlexLuya: [`[\\x{4e00}-\\x{9fa5}]` finds a match in that string](https://regex101.com/r/jP8bO9/1). [So does `\p{Han}`](https://regex101.com/r/jP8bO9/2)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38656686/why-does-mariadb-regex-give-contrary-result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MariaDB uses **PCRE** regex library beginning with 10.0.5 version: "[*Starting with MariaDB 10.0.5, MariaDB switched to the PCRE regular expression library for enhanced regular expressions.*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/pcre/)".

**To match entries that contain Chinese letters** use

```
REGEXP '[\\x{4e00}-\\x{9fa5}]'
```

or even

```
REGEXP '\\p{Han}'
```

To match the reverse, **entries with no Chinese letters**, use:

```
REGEXP '^[^\\x{4e00}-\\x{9fa5}]*$'
```

or

```
REGEXP '^\\P{Han}*$'
```

Comment: Stribizew, SELECT `name` FROM `table`  WHERE `name` REGEXP '^\\p{Han}*$',won't match entries with no Chinese letters,but pure Chinese word.

Comment: Yes, I know. `'^\\p{Han}*$'` matches a string that only consists of Chinese letters. And `'^\\P{Han}*$'` will match a string that consists of characters other than Chinese letters. Note the uppercase `P` in the latter regex that means we are reversing the Unicode property class.